# Does the Rescue Ranger do damage to sappers?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

I was wondering if a spy starts sapping my building if I shoot it with my Rescue Ranger will it damage and eventually remove the sapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** it will not. A rescue ranger shot will repair the building slightly but will not remove the sapper. Only an engineer's wrench or a pyro's homewrecker or neon annihilator can remove sappers.

Source: [TF2 Wiki - Rescue Ranger](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Rescue_Ranger)